# I can't get Javascript to work out of order

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm putting a website together, and I have a row of social icons at the bottom. I'm using Javascript to replace the image with a different color when they're hovered over.

The issue is that the images will only change once I've started with the first one. I want users to be able to hover over any of them at any time and have it work. Any thoughts?

Here's my code, if it helps:

HTML:

```
<div class="socialrow">
    <a href="[Twitter Link]"><img src="img/twittericon.png" class="twitterbutton" alt="Twitter"></a>
    <a href="[Facebook Link]"><img src="img/facebookicon.png" class="facebookbutton" alt="Facebook"></a>
    <a href="[LinkedIn Link]"><img src="img/linkedinicon.png" class="linkedinbutton" alt="LinkedIn"></a>
    <a href="[Tumblr Link]"><img src="img/tumblricon.png" class="tumblrbutton" alt="Tumblr"></a>
    <a href="[Instagram Link]"><img src="img/instagramicon.png" class="instagrambutton" alt="Instagram"></a>
    <a href="[Google+ Link]"><img src="img/googleplusicon.png" class="googleplusbutton" alt="Google+"></a>
</div><!-- end socialrow -->
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".twitterbutton").hover(function () {
        $(this).attr("src", "img/twitterred.png");
    }, function () {
        $(this).attr("src", "img/twittericon.png");
        $(".facebookbutton").hover(function () {
            $(this).attr("src", "img/facebookred.png");
        }, function () {
            $(this).attr("src", "img/facebookicon.png");
            $(".linkedinbutton").hover(function () {
                $(this).attr("src", "img/linkedinred.png");
            }, function () {
                $(this).attr("src", "img/linkedinicon.png");
                $(".tumblrbutton").hover(function () {
                    $(this).attr("src", "img/tumblrred.png");
                }, function () {
                    $(this).attr("src", "img/tumblricon.png");
                    $(".instagrambutton").hover(function () {
                        $(this).attr("src", "img/instagramred.png");
                    }, function () {
                        $(this).attr("src", "img/instagramicon.png");
                        $(".googleplusbutton").hover(function () {
                            $(this).attr("src", "img/googleplusred.png");
                        }, function () {
                            $(this).attr("src", "img/googleplusicon.png");
                        });
                    });
                });
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Look how your code is nested (thanks @j08691 for formatting). You only define hover on facebook once you mouseout twitter, and so on...

Comment: Woah. I suggest you pause working on this code and gain a little better understanding of the tools you are using. This... I don't know why you would do it like this. Have you seen this in a tutorial? In the jQuery docs? Where... who.... why!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know tihs is answered already but I wouldn't use Javascript at all for this.

You can use this with the images you already have:

```
<a href="http://www.facebook.com/foo" class="social facebook">Facebook</a>

.social {
  display: block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-indent: 110%;
}

.social.facebook {
  background-image: url("img/facebookicon.png")
}

.social.facebook:hover {
  background-image: url("img/facebookred.png") 
}
```

You could also look into creating a sprite, which would basically be one image with all the images in there and you just rerepostion the background image when it's hovered.

If you're feeling brave you can also look into icon fonts, which I think would be your best option. You can change the size, color and anything else you can do to regular text and they're infinitely scaleable. Here's a pretty popular one (http://fontawesome.io/icons/), but you can build your own fairly easily (http://icomoon.io/app/#/select)

Answer (score 4):

Try something a little more dynamic

```
$('.socialrow a').on('mouseenter mouseleave', function(e) {
    $('img', this).prop('src', function(_,src) {
        return e.type=='mouseenter' ? src.replace('icon', 'red') : src.replace('red', 'icon');
    });
});
```

Comment: @user3067342 Indeed. Look up a tutorial and spend some time with the docs: http://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/ :)

Answer (score 0):

Don't use JavaScript for this, use CSS.

```
a.twitter-icon {
    background: url('twitter-icon.jpg');
}

a.twitter-icon:hover {
    background: url('twitter-icon-hover.jpg');
}
```